# is there a way to show a href link using an if / else statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I got some css images that I've coded. Each css image is in a href link currently. Is there a way to do some if / else logic to say if a button is clicked then show the link else if its not clicked then don't show the link?

I've added a jsfiddle for someone to look at 
https://jsfiddle.net/lr16/kvo76x03/

The current code is below

```
<button id="reveal">
Reveal
</button>

if(reveal.click == true){
    $('happycharacterone.php');
} else if(reveal.click == false) {
    $('');
}
```

Currently the if / else statement doesn't show the link is there a way to show it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/854paLz3/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jquery click action

```
<button id="reveal">Reveal</button>

<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>


   $("button").click(function(){
      var value = $(this).html();
      switch(value){
        case "Reveal":
          alert("reveal")
        break;

       case "Cancel":
          alert("cancel")
        break;

       default:

        break;
     }
  });
```

Here is the [fiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/kvo76x03/10/)

Answer (score 0):

U can do this

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('a').hide();
  $('.reveal').click(function()
  {
    $('a').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="reveal">reveal link</button><br>
<a href="Image1.png">image 1</a>
```